# Pip install from local directory

Tags: python, pip

I am installing from a local project:

```
cd myProject
pip install -e .
```

My current virtual environment is "rasa-new-envs". I thought myProject will be installed into the following virtual environment:

```
/my-envs/rasa-new-envs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
```

I checked this directory, but my project are not installed into site-packages/ directory, and the installation message says the installation is successful. Why is that?

By "pip install -e .", the installed dependencies stay in the original directory? Thanks.

My pip:

```
(rasa-new-envs) congmins-MacBook-Pro:rasa_nlu lingvisa$ pip -V
pip 19.0.3 from /Users/lingvisa/Nlp/my-envs/rasa-new-envs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

Comment: Do a `which pip`.  You are probably using pip2.7

Comment: The editable install (`-e`) doesn't copy the sources, but only creates a link file which points to your working directory. This comes handy when developing code; if you want to do a proper install, omit `-e`: `pip install .`

Comment: That makes sense!!!

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs